# SSL key decryption

Tags: tls, key-management, rsa, decryption

I am wondering if I can get the SSL Key given the following conditions:

```
Encrypted Text is known 
Decrypted Text is known
```

Any ideas on how I can create a program that does this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## No.

This would be a [Known-plaintext attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Known-plaintext_attack). And SSL/TLS is hardened against that.

This is the very high level essence of it.

SSL/TLS is actually hybrid crypto. This means that a symmetric session key is encrypted or signed with an asymmetric crypto system.

Now with your known plaintext attack you might in principle be able to derive the session key. This would mean that you have cracked the symmetric part. Now that you have the plaintext session key and the ciphertext session key you could then attack the asymmetric (public key) part of SSL/TLS. Which might then allow you to crack what you call the "SSL Key".

But other than in disastrously (even comically) misconfigured systems your amounts of known plaintext are nowhere close to enough.

(In correctly configured systems even several terabytes of known plaintext are not nearly enough.)